# Laravel update record in hasMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

listing_agents table has structure:

```
Schema::create('listing_agents', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('listing_id')->default('0');
    $table->integer('agent_id')->default('0');
    $table->integer('commission')->default('0');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

My Model is:

```
public function listing_agents()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\ListingAgent', 'listing_id');
}
```

My controller is

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
$data = $request->all();
$listing = Listing::find($id);
$listing->update($data);
$agents = $request->agents;
$item = [];
$item['listing_id'] = $listing->id;
$item['agent_id'] = [];
foreach($agents as $agent) {
    array_push($item['agent_id'], $agent["key"]);
}

if($listing) {
    $listing->listing_agents()->update($item['agent_id']);
}
```

I am getting below error:

```
"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: update `listing_agents` set `0` = 78, `1` = 84, `listing_agents`.`updated_at` = 2021-01-06 01:59:50 where `listing_agents`.`listing_id` = 60 and `listing_agents`.`listing_id` is not null)"
```

If I change above to:

```
foreach($agents as $agent) {
//array_push($item['agent_id'], $agent["key"]);
    $listing->listing_agents()->update(['agent_id' => $item['agent_id']]);
}
```

This is not updating any record. I wanted to update the record with a single eloquent query like I am inserting.
`$listing = Listing::create($data);` and `$listing->listing_agents()->createMany($agents);`

This is how my db record looks like:
https://ibb.co/c24mqgR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now I am updating record using this way.

```
if($listing) {
    $listing->listing_agents()->delete();
    $listing->listing_agents()->createMany($agents);
}
```

I am not accepting this answer. If you can post better answer than this, please post your answer so that I can mark that as accepted answer.